# CentOS 6 "Default" Installation Options

Tags: centos, system-installation

Can someone tell me the difference between a Desktop Install, a Basic Server install, and a Minimal Install? During installation, it doesn't give a description and I can't find documentation on it either.

This is for a CentOS 6 installation.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As you've already noticed, [Red Hat's description](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Installation_Guide/index.html#s1-pkgselection-x86) is vague about what each suite actually includes. Below is a list of the package groups the each suite will install.

You can get more information about what package group by running `yum groupinfo foo-bar`. The names listed below differ from what `yum grouplist` will list but the groupinfo cobase, console-internet, core, debugging, directory-client, hardware-monitoring, java-platform, large-systems, network-file-system-client, performance, perl-runtime, server-platformmmand still works on them.

I got this by mounting http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/images/install.img and looking at /usr/lib/anaconda/installclasses/rhel.py inside the image.

**Desktop**: base, basic-desktop, core, debugging, desktop-debugging, desktop-platform, directory-client, fonts, general-desktop, graphical-admin-tools, input-methods, internet-applications, internet-browser, java-platform, legacy-x, network-file-system-client, office-suite, print-client, remote-desktop-clients, server-platform, x11

**Minimal Desktop**: base, basic-desktop, core, debugging, desktop-debugging, desktop-platform, directory-client, fonts, input-methods, internet-browser, java-platform, legacy-x, network-file-system-client, print-client, remote-desktop-clients, server-platform, x11

**Minimal**: core

**Basic Server**: base, console-internet, core, debugging, directory-client, hardware-monitoring, java-platform, large-systems, network-file-system-client, performance, perl-runtime, server-platform

**Database Server**: base, console-internet, core, debugging, directory-client, hardware-monitoring, java-platform, large-systems, network-file-system-client, performance, perl-runtime, server-platform, mysql-client, mysql, postgresql-client, postgresql, system-admin-tools

**Web Server**: base, console-internet, core, debugging, directory-client, java-platform, mysql-client, network-file-system-client, performance, perl-runtime, php, postgresql-client, server-platform, turbogears, web-server, web-servlet

**Virtual Host**: base, console-internet, core, debugging, directory-client, hardware-monitoring, java-platform, large-systems, network-file-system-client, performance, perl-runtime, server-platform, virtualization, virtualization-client, virtualization-platform

**Software Development Workstation**: additional-devel, base, basic-desktop, core, debugging, desktop-debugging, desktop-platform, desktop-platform-devel, development, directory-client, eclipse, emacs, fonts, general-desktop, graphical-admin-tools, graphics, input-methods, internet-browser, java-platform, legacy-x, network-file-system-client, performance, perl-runtime, print-client, remote-desktop-clients, server-platform, server-platform-devel, technical-writing, tex, virtualization, virtualization-client, virtualization-platform, x11

Comment: Basic Server and Database Server are exactly the same in your list. Can that be correct?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting I must've copied and pasted wrong. I updated the list to correct the Database Server section.

Answer (score 5):

[The Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Installation Guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Installation_Guide/index.html) section [9.17. Package Group Selection](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Installation_Guide/index.html#s1-pkgselection-x86) provides some information, but it's not much:

> By default, the Red Hat Enterprise Linux installation process loads a
>   selection of software that is suitable for a system deployed as a
>   basic server. Note that this installation does not include a graphical
>   environment. To include a selection of software suitable for other
>   roles, click the radio button that corresponds to one of the following
>   options:
>
> **Basic Server**
>
> This option provides a basic installation of Red
>   Hat Enterprise Linux for use on a server.
>
> **Desktop**
>
> This option provides the OpenOffice.org productivity suite, graphical tools such as > the GIMP, and multimedia applications.
>
> **Minimal**
>
> This option provides only the packages essential to run
>   Red Hat Enterprise Linux. A minimal installation provides the basis
>   for a single-purpose server or desktop appliance and maximizes
>   performance and security on such an installation.

Comment: +1 yeah that's all I found as well. I was hoping that there was some site that has package information for the installs. I suppose we'll just go with the one we 'think' will get us the packages we need then install whatever else =( I'll leave this as unanswered for a day to see if anyone has an informative link for the different installs.

Comment: I ask this [same darn question (or a similar one) every couple of years](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/yum-what-package-group-can-provide-a-package-760652/). Someday I may actually find a good answer.

Comment: lol. Maybe when they `chmod a-laziness dev-team` they'll document it better =P