# What kind of installation should I choose from CentOS to have it as dom0 xen host?

Tags: centos, system-installation, xen

I want to have CentOS 6.0 x86_64 as a dom0 xen host. During the installation of CentOS there are many options for installation: "minimal" "Basic Server"... "Virtual Host".. 
The question is: which one should I select? Is it "virtual host" or can I go with "Basic server" or "minimal" (which is the default)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this wonderful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20379/centos-6-default-installation-options/20528#20528) to [a related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20379/11539) reveals the **differences between the package groups of "Basic Server" and "Virtual Host"**:

> **Basic Server:** base, console-internet, core, debugging, directory-client, hardware-monitoring, java-platform, large-systems, network-file-system-client, performance, perl-runtime, server-platform

**Virtual Host** = **Basic Server** + virtualization, virtualization-client, virtualization-platform

Thus the first guess would be that Virtual Host is best suited; *but* looking at the [RedHat virtualization guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization/index.html) the "virtualization-*" package groups probably mean KVM.  Now, [here](http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/RHEL6Xen4Tutorial) you'll find information about Xen 4 and a RHEL dom0, including links to binary repositories.  This suggests **choosing "Basic Server"**, or just to follow [the linked tutorial](http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/RHEL6Xen4Tutorial), they start with "Basic Server", too.

Comment: The RedHat links are all dead.