# CentOS 6 installs libmysqlclient.so.16 and friends without me asking

Tags: centos, dependencies

Whilst trying to resolve a dependency issue with MySQL's `libmysqlclient` libraries on one of my CentOS 6 MySQL servers I was surprised to discover the following libraries installed in `/usr/lib/mysql`:

```
libmysqlclient_r.so -> libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
libmysqlclient_r.so.16 -> libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
libmysqlclient.so.16 -> libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
```

The reason I was surprised was because this server has only ever had MySQL 5.5 installed which was built from source. Building MySQL 5.5 produces a set of `libmysqlclient.so.18` libraries, not `libmysqlclient.so.16`.

I then built a brand new CentOS 6 (i386) server from scratch and installed *only* the Base package group and nothing else (i.e. no HTTP server, no MySQL, no Gnome etc). Having scanned the packages in this group there was nothing that jumped out at me as having a dependency on `libmysqlclient`.

However when the install completed, there sitting in the `/usr/lib` directory was a `mysql` folder containing the above `libmysqlclient.so.16` libraries.

I then built a CentOS 5.5 (i386) server using only the Base packages as I did with CentOS 6 and these MySQL libraries do not get installed.

This appears to be a new thing, is there any reason why a Base package install of CentOS 6 requires `libmysqlclient` to be installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement for MySQL to be installed on CentOS 6.

Assuming "using only the Base packages" means you selected "Basic Server" or "Minimal" when you did the install, it was pulled in as a dependency for the `core` group. `core` includes postfix which depends on `mysql-libs` which is what provides /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.

[CentOS 6 "Default" Installation Options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20379/3852) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Yep, postfix (2.6.6) is the culprit. I just had a look at the source RPM spec file for 2.3.3 which is the version that comes with CentOS 5.5-5.7 and the `mysql-libs` dependency is turned off.