# Centos 6.5 from Desktop to basic server

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I have already installed centos6.5 on a virtualbox, and I realized that I missed choosing the the basic server mode,can I change it now that the installation is over ?

Comment: I guess you just need to change the default init level to 3, and remove and X packages.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between Basic Server and Desktop is just the type of packages that are installed.  These just represent different starting points for an installation.  Typically, as you work on your server and find you need "server" programs that were not installed in the Desktop version, you can easily install them with `yum`.

If you want to make sure you have all of the Basic Server packages from the get-go, you can run:

```
yum groupinstall base, console-internet, core, debugging, directory-client, hardware-monitoring, java-platform, large-systems, network-file-system-client, performance, perl-runtime, server-platform
```

This won't remove any of the Desktop packages that aren't included in a Basic Server install.  You can remove those with

```
yum groupremove basic-desktop, desktop-debugging, fonts, general-desktop, graphical-admin-tools, input-methods, internet-applications, internet-browser, legacy-x, office-suite, print-client, remote-desktop-clients, x11
yum remove atk cairo dbus fontconfig freetype gtk2 libICE libSM libX11 libXext libXft libXi libXrender libXt libXtst libpng mesa-libGL mesa-libGLU pango qt qt3 redhat-lsb-graphics redhat-lsb-printing
```

This will remove all graphical applications, including `X` and `gnome`.  The second line corresponds to manually removing each package in the `desktop-platform` group.  This group includes `glib2` and `libxml2`, which cannot be removed and so were excluded from this list.

This list of groups that each form of installation uses was taken from this excellent [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20528/34796).